# Basic question on the Langlands conjectures for $GL_n$ over global field of positive characteristic

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures, global-fields

My field is far from the Langlands conjectures. I am just trying to understand some basic ideas.

At the moment I am interested in a global field $K$ of positive characteristic and the group $G=GL_n$. As far as I heard in this case the conjectures are solved.

In particular, if I understand correctly, there is a bijection between cuspidal representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{A}_K)$ and isomorphism classes of irreducible $l$-adic $n$-dimensional representations of the absolute Galois group of $K$.

**I am wondering whether automorphic representations which are not cuspidal play any role in the theory. Do they correspond to reducible representations of the Galois group?**

**UPDATE:** As it was mentioned in a comment below by Kenta Suzuki, over local fields non-cuspidal representations do play a role and correspond to reducible representations of the Galois group.

Comment: Under the local Langlands correspondence, noncuspidal representations correspond to reducible Galois representations. I am not sure about global fields though.